# N-tire EntityLayer Do I create Class based on Database Table or WebForm in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, entity

I am trying to Implement N-tire concept in my Hospital Management Project. In my project requirement I have to make a Patient Diagnosis WebForm which 1st takes patient Diagnosis information then "Saves" those information then it takes billing information. In the database I have 2 table one holds Diagnosis information another holds Billing information.

So, I am wondering which is better/correct approach. To create 2 different classes in the Entity Layer for this 2 tables OR, Create 1 Class for the webform and keep all the WebForm Information in that single class.

Here is a Screen Shot of the webform:

[image: WebForm]

And Here is the EntityLayer Class I have written, So Far following the 2nd approach:

```
 public class EntityEnterPatientDiagnosisDetails
   {
        public int PatientId { get; set; }
        public string Symptoms { get; set; }
        public string DiagnosisProvided { get; set;}
        public string AdministeredBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateofDiagnosis { get; set; }
        public string FollowUpRequired { get; set; }
        public DateTime FollowUpDate { get; set; }



        /// <summary>
        /// Bill Part
        /// </summary>
        public int BillAmount { get; set; }
        public string ModeOfPayment { get; set; }
        public string CardNumber { get; set; }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information given you should have at least 3 classes; Patient, Diagnosis and Billing.  Billing is an accounting entity and credit card details have no business in a medical diagnostics record.

Comment: patientId is taken from tblPatient . So, I should create individual classes for individual Database table .

Answer (score 0):

Bluer,

you need to to do the communication with your database in your Data Access Layer of your asp.net project in Visual Studio. It can be created by some [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) tool such as EntityFramework or NHibernate or SubSonic. Or it can simply be implemented with [ADO.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET). Regardless of which approach you take you need to have as much entity classes as you have database tables and also the relation(1:m,m:m) between those tables.

The approach you're making is similar to MVC design pattern, where you're creating a 'ViewModel' of your needs, where you're combining several entities which is also good.

You can try to have one page (WebForm) for the diagnosis details, fill the data then click save(post) and send to DAL to save the diagnosis. Then you can display a link(after the post back) which will be navigating to the payments page (WebForm) where you'll fill the details and then click save button to send the data to DAL for saving payments into database.

Comment: " also the relation(1:m,m:m) between those tables" can you explain this part. In Entity Framework there is a "navigation propertits" to create relationship between tables. So, I can do that by creating property for the keys in the classes. But in M:M relationship we usually create a separate table in DB for creating relation between 2 tables. In Entity Framework how do I manage to do that?                                                                                     Also how can i set the PK since billID is auto generated .So, I  would need to save that id in the diagnosis table as well.

Comment: First create the tables in database: Patien[Id, FirstName, LastName]; Phisycian[Id,FirstName,LastName,Speciality]; Diagnosis[Id, PatientId, Symptoms, Diagnosis, AdministeredById,Date, FolowUpRequired, FolowUpDate]; Biling[Id, DiagnosisId, Amount, Mode]. Then in Visual Studio in the edmx file you can right click and choose 'Update Model from Database', then the EF will generate all the EF classes and appropriate relations.